# What is view method doing on numpy matrix that changes the shape?

Tags: python

So I have a function:

```
def create_vecs(colnames):
    return np.matrix(data[colnames]).view(dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, 3)
```

when I apply this function on my data, first part gets the columns of interest and returns a numpy matrix of size 1340*3. but then I'm not sure what view is doing on my data that it doesn't let my data to be reshaped to three columns. I'm confused how this view method works and how to change it so that I can reshape my data back to three columns.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "that it doesn't let my data to be reshaped to three columns"?

Answer (score -1):

When you say:

```
.reshape(-1, 3)
```

python reshape so that the second index be 3 unit and first index adapts to whatever it gets

for example 1340*3 you have 4020 unit data

so if you use

```
.reshape(-1, 5, 4)
```

the shape of the matrix becomes

```
(201, 5, 4)
```

I hope i was clear.

Comment: What is that view method doing? I know how reshape works but how does view changes my data that I can't reshape it later as it won't be divisible by three.

Comment: In your code view changes the numpy array format to float64 you can get more information from here about view [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)